# How to take intervals on generic Event observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a simple observable that tracks mouse movement:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<MouseEventArgs>> mouseTracker = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(form1, "MouseMove");
mouseTracker.Subscribe(evt =>
{
    rxLabel.Text = evt.EventArgs.Location.ToString();
});
```

How to attach Interval() method to this observable ? All its code samples mention "Console.WriteLine", which is not suitable for this case.

```
IObservable<TimeInterval<long>> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750)).TimeInterval();
using (observable.Subscribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Interval)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "attach Interval" ? do you want to combine the interval stream and your mouse event stream in some way ?

Comment: @Gluck : yes, exactly. I want to be able to periodically sample the mouse tracking event.

Comment: And I assume [sample](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html) operator isn't just what you're looking for ? :) if so, how so ?

Comment: @Gluck : Looks promising. How to attach sample operator to  mouseTracker? Its usage looks similar to Interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gluck's comment is correct. You can use `Sample` to do this. It can take either a `TimeSpan` or an `Observable` as an argument. The first variant simply tries to sample every x amount of time. The second variant will try to emit every time the sampling `Observable` emits.

Usage would be like so:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<MouseEventArgs>> mouseTracker = 
    Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(form1, "MouseMove");

//Will emit the latest value from mouseTracker, every 750 milliseconds
IObservable<EventPattern<MouseEventArgs>> sampledTracker = 
    mouseTracker.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750));

sampledTracker
.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
.Subscribe(evt =>
{
    rxLabel.Text = evt.EventArgs.Location.ToString();
});
```

**Edit**

I added synchronization code since sample will by default not operator on the UI thread.

Comment: I want to have this as the correct answer, however, looks like Sample is unreliable. My form is frozen after few intervals. What did I do wrong ? I am using Rx 2.2.5, .NET 4.5.2. Snippets: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mjieU4

Comment: The problem seems to be within your thread synchronization code. Rx already has methods for synchronizing back to your main thread you shouldn't roll your own. That is use `ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)` not `InvokeIfRequired()`